# Stop running code based on result of sub macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have structure like:

```
Private Sub CreateNewQP()
        If oObjectSearchResults.Count = 0 Then
        Else
        MsgBox "There is already QP with the same version"
        End If
End Sub
```

Then I call this code from Master macro:

```
Sub TryToDoEverything()

On Error Resume Next

    Call CreateNewQP
...
```

How I can stop `TryToDoEverything` if `MsgBox "There is already QP with the same version"` will appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use `End` as Well**. As an Example try to run the `Test1` in the Below code:

```
Sub test1()


    MsgBox "Test1"

    Call test2

    MsgBox "This should not be printed"

End Sub
Sub test2()


    MsgBox "test3"

    End

End Sub
```

So the second `MsgBox` in `Test1` will not Print Anything. If you remove the `End` line in `Test2`, you will see the MsgBox saying this should not be Printed. And you can put the `End` in your `If Conditon`. Simple and Easy.

---

**Demo:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can change the inner subroutine into a function, have it return a value, check said value, and exit parent subroutine if value matches.

Something like below should work:

```
Private Function Inner()
    ResponseInner = MsgBox("I should stop outer.")
    Inner = ResponseInner
End Function

Sub Outer()
    Debug.Print "Calling Inner"
    ResponseOuter = Inner
    If ResponseOuter = 1 Then 'Should return a 1 if OK was pressed in Inner.
        Exit Sub
        Debug.Print "I should't print."
    End If
End Sub
```

Which gives the following result:

[image]

Of course it goes to follow that you should terminate parent sub properly (turn on `Application.ScreenUpdating` if you turned it off, etc.).

Comment: This is more advanced solution. I have to learn functions. Upped, but I will mark second one as solution because of my limited knowledge of functions so far.

Comment: @user7202022 All good. Functions would be vastly superior in the long run though as you can control the flow based on other more advanced responses (for example, MsgBoxes that return more than just `OK` or `Cancel`, etc.). Highly recommend you learn it.